# Package dependency issues with postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

I'm running **Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS "Trusty"**

Whenever I try to install postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 the following comes up:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1 : Depends: libgdal1 (>= 1.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Other people have had this issue and it seems to be a conflict between **libgdal1** and **libgdal1h**, however I haven't been able to resolve this with the answers they received.

I've tried:

1. `sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1`, same issue.
2. `sudo apt-get install libgdal1`, which returns multiple unmet dependency issues.
3. Adding UbuntuGIS stable and untsable PPAs and then trying to install libgdal1 from there with `sudo apt-get install libgdal1/ubuntugis` (also with `/ubuntugis-unstable` and `/ppa` - I wasn't sure on the syntax even though I searched. All return "release was not found" messages.
4. I tried #3 because I thought `apt-cache policy postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1` was telling me that it would download it by default from http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ - however, in retrospect, I'm assuming that it simply lists the repositories it detects as having the package available, which would explain why #3 didn't work.
5. Continuing from #4, I tried `apt-cache policy postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1.4` (9.3 instead of 9.4) and specified 2.1.4 because as a specific version it's listed as being exclusively available from http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/

None of the above have been able to resolve the issue and I'm at a loss as to what to try next, especially with results such as: https://askubuntu.com/questions/615767/how-to-install-postgresql-9-4-postgis-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04trusty-tahr where the solution provided doesn't appear to work, at least not with this set-up.

While I can search, read and try things all of this is unfamiliar territory for me.

Any pointers in the right direction (or possible solutions as it's "only" a question of getting **libdgal1** installed AFAIK) would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that I was using the wrong repository. If anyone runs into this issue then make sure that when you add the PostgreSQL repository you've used the **codename** that corresponds to your Ubuntu.

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ CODENAME-pgdg main
```

Replace codename with what you find with:

```
lsb_release -c
```

Comment: Hmmm, what if my repository is missing (vivid):
http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/
?

Comment: I was having similar issues and noticed that I'd added the precise-pgdg repo, instead of trusty (I'm on 14.04).

Once I'd corrected that error, I was able to do:

sudo apt-get install postgresql   (which gave me 9.5)

and

sudo apt-get install postgis (which gave me 2.2)

Answer (score 1):

Solution for me on Ubuntu 15.04 (vivid) was to remove `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list.d` altogether, to allow the **postgresql-9.4** and  **postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1** packages be installed from the main ubuntu repositories.
There is no postgresql apt for vivid.

Comment: This is all well and good for 15.10 and later, but doesn't help for 14.04, where the package manager will instal postgresql9.3 by default

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same issue, what i do: enter to **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/** and remove all pgdg files.

In my attempts i added a ppa named: **ubuntugis-ubuntugis-unstable-trusty** , so i removed it too.

Then it works :)

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands to install `postgresql` and `postgis`:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install postgis
```